# varying sizes of rows in table for any particular column using swt/Jface

Tags: java, swt, jface

Please let me know how to get  varying sizes of rows in table for any particular column using swt/Jface?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082082/swt-table-with-variable-row-height-working-on-linux-but-not-mac-windows) related question.

Table rows with different height is possible in Linux, but not Windows.

You can have a look at alternative table widgets like Nebula's [`Grid`](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php).

[`KTable`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktable/) can merge/span table rows:

[image]

Comment: yes i did have a look at(Nebula, NatTable,Ktable,SWT-Matrix) Only row level height can be changed. But what if i want for only particular column.

Comment: @user1925819 Well, what would that look like?

Comment: I can't attach screenshot, hence i am providing link (http://eaddress.co.kr/sbstory/03sales/dmsalepage.asp). You can see the row with varying sizes.

Comment: @user1925819 You won't be able to do that with an SWT/JFace table. However, [KTable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktable/) can do that.

Comment: I know about this, but issue is integrating some SWT fields with Ktable.If u see screenshot there is search criteria which uses SWT textbox, radio button based on that search result will be displayed in table.Will this be supported by Ktable.